# style social media buttons with CSS?

Tags: css, twitter, facebook-like, google-plus

I'm using Twitter's tweet button, Facebook's like button and Google's +1 button. I've tried styling them with my own external CSS file as well as inline CSS. But, it seems that no matter what adjustments I make to the CSS, it ultimately gets overruled by either FB's, twitter's or Google's CSS from their API. I need to make the buttons found [here](http://sportannica.com/predictions/38/) line up neatly. I tried setting the floats of each button to left. But, that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use !important to make sure your style rules get applied.

For example,

```
button {
   padding: 4px !important;
}
```

If the facebook, twitter, whatever framework sets the button's padding to 8px, this would reset it to 4px.

**Working example**: http://jsfiddle.net/yLEwS/. Try removing `!important` from both lines and see what happens.

Comment: Um. Sorry. I'm not a designer first and foremost. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: If you add !important to a CSS rule, it will override whatever else is more specific than it. It's a way of saying, "Hey, apply my style no matter what."

Comment: Cool. That's nice to know. I never knew such a rule existed in CSS. It works like a charm. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Pro tip: keep in mind that as you override the Google+ +1 button CSS, it still needs to adhere to our branding guidelines.  You can find these at https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines.